# When to allocate Random object in Java

Tags: java

Is it more beneficial to keep a single Random object in every class that requires it, or is it better to create a Random object on the fly? Clearly, there's standard memory usage and garbage collector considerations, as there are for all objects, but I'm wondering whether a new Random object differs from an already used Random object in any way.

Does the state of a Random object change as it's used?

Comment: "_Does the state of a `Random` object change as it's used_" - oh heavens **YES**. In fact, creating a `new Random()` too often can result in it generating the _same_ number sequence - i.e. multiple instances created with the same seed. Depending on the quality of the randomness required it is incredibly important to use the right random class and create it at the right time. See [Linear Congruential Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Actually, [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) explicitly state “Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe.”

Comment: @VGR fair point - my mistake. It's just very slow - now I remember